# Make a Dictionary with 2 lists, one list containing the indexes of the other

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 lists:

```
first = ['33', '44', '55', '66', '77', '88', '99', '22']
second = [['1 6'], ['2 7'], ['3 4'], ['5 0'], 
          ['3'], ['6'], ['0'], ['4 1']]
```

And I want to make a dictionary that takes the values of the first list as keys, and also takes the values of the first lists as elements, taking the element of the second list as the index for choosing which element of the first list will be as an element in a key.

So it has to look like this at the end:

```
d = {'33' : ['44', '99'], '44' : ['55', '22'], 
     '55' : ['66', '77'], '66' : ['88', '33'], 
     '77' : ['55'], '88' : ['99'], '99' : ['33'], 
     '22' : ['77', '44']}
```

Comment: Why are your values in the second list wraped into single element lists. I'm fairly sure this is not the format you want to have.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Comment: As the first comment states, the format of your second list is rather strange, though it is possible to use the format you have. Are you sure that second list is correct? And do tell us some of your work on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with `zip`:

```
first = ['33', '44', '55', '66', '77', '88', '99', '22']
second = [['1 6'], ['2 7'], ['3 4'], ['5 0'],  ['3'], ['6'], ['0'], ['4 1']]
final_result = {a:[first[i] for i in map(int, b.split())] for a, [b] in zip(first, second)}
```

Output:

```
{'33': ['44', '99'], '44': ['55', '22'], '55': ['66', '77'], '66': ['88', '33'], '77': ['66'], '88': ['99'], '99': ['33'], '22': ['77', '44']}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are attempting to generate a graph from a list of values and an adjacency list.

My first remark would be that your `second` list should contain lists of indices instead of single strings wrapped into a list.

By example the first entry...

```
['1 6']
```

... would become this.

```
[1, 6]
```

Notice how we are now using `int` elements which more meaningfully represent indices.

Once you switch to this format, you can more efficiently handle it to generate a graph using a `dict`.

## Example

```
first = ['33', '44', '55', '66']
second = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3], [0]]

graph = {}
for value, indices in zip(first, second):
    graph[value] = [first[i] for i in indices]
```

## Output

```
# graph
{'33': ['44', '55'],
 '44': ['55', '66'],
 '55': ['66'],
 '66': ['33']
}
```

## Converting the adjacency list

In the event you are already commited to the format of `second`, here is how to convert it.

```
second = [[int(x) for x in l[0].split()] for l in second]
```